# UIView's subviews or components Not Moving With View

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have 3 UIViews and added 3 labels to each view as subview. When I resize the views, so that their height becomes zero, still all 3 labels are visible.

And one more point that, initially the labels are at the center of UIViews but when I increase views height, they(labels) do not remain to the center of views.

Does any body know what is this and solution to this?

Comment: By default views do not clip there subviews. This is why when you set the height to zero you still see the lebels. If you want to change this set `clipsToBounds` to `YES` for the container views.

If you want to position the labels at the centre of the views you need to use autolayout for this

Comment: thanks for your answer, but autolayout is not available in xcode 4.6 its in xcode 5.0 and it do not support ios 6. Then any alternative to do this.

Comment: Autolayout was introduced in iOS 6 so it should be ok. If you need to support older iOS versions you can use autoresizingMask (old Springs and Struts way).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UIView property `clipsToBounds` is set to `NO` by default. Set the property to `YES` to avoid showing subviews outside of the current bounds.

Answer (score 0):

you can use autoresizing to manage that if you don't use autolayout.